# How to clip content along border-radius?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend

I am building a chatbot having a special design that includes a rotated div at the top.
I want to clip my header division around the border.

Here in this example, I am unable to maintain `border-radius: 29px;` for my chat widget on the top-left and top-right parts in my `header-part` class.

Please guide me on this issue.
Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Chatbot</title>

  <style>
    .chatbot-main {
      width: 431px;
      height: 719px;
      border-radius: 29px;
      background-color: #f2f4f9;
      margin: 20px
    }
    
    .header-part {
      padding: 20px;
      height: 125px;
      background-color: #21f5a8;
      border-top-left-radius: 29px;
      border-top-right-radius: 29px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 26px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 26px;
      clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
    }
    
    .company-header {
      background-color: #0caa63;
      display: block;
      width: 453.3px;
      height: 170px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 4px;
      top: -85.38px;
      transform: rotate(-2.86deg);
    }
    
    .support-header {
      position: absolute;
      top: 130px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chatbot-main">
    <div class="header-part">
      <div class="company-header">Chatbot</div>
      <div class="support-header">
        you are talking to support assistant
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: overflow: hidden; to chatbot-main ?

Comment: Almost right, but some minor UI issue occurs in the transform rotate part

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
```

to your `.header-part`

Example:

```css
.chatbot-main {
  width: 431px;
  height: 719px;
  border-radius: 29px;
  background-color: #f2f4f9;
  margin: 20px
}

.header-part {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: #21f5a8;
  border-top-left-radius: 29px;
  border-top-right-radius: 29px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 26px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 26px;
  clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.company-header {
  background-color: #0caa63;
  display: block;
  width: 453.3px;
  height: 170px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: -85.38px;
  transform: rotate(-2.86deg);
}

.support-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbot-main">
  <div class="header-part">
    <div class="company-header">Chatbot</div>
    <div class="support-header">
      you are talking to support assistant
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to do that, but still, my feedback is recorded